# get payment method title of an order

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I want to show payment method of an order in **My Orders** customer page.

I have tried use `echo $_order->getPaymentMethod()`, it gives NULL variable.

I also tried `echo $block->getpaymentsCollection()->getTitle()`, it shows messy looks without error.

So, what is correct way to show payment method title of an order?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Get the payment model from the order, then get the method instance from the payment:

```
    $payment = $order->getPayment();
    $method = $payment->getMethodInstance();
    $methodTitle = $method->getTitle();
```

Where `$order` is an instance of `Magento\Sales\Model\Order`.

Comment: `Magento\Sales\Model\Order` is not called from the used block.

Comment: `$_order` in the **My Orders** page template is a `Magento\Sales\Model\Order`.

Comment: forget my deleted comments. I just didn't pay attention :)

Comment: I get this error. **Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Area code is not set** can you please help me @AaronAllen

Answer (score 2):

```
$_order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation("method_title")
```

Comment: Please add more details about your code for better understanding

Comment: What? If You have Magento\Sales\Model\Order object, You can get payment method title using line above. What do You want to know more? You don't need payment method instance. Just get method title from additional information.