# Magento 1.9 : How to combine two collection data?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, join

I have two different collection one is of order payment transaction and other one is of sales order as show below:

```
$transactionData=Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment_transaction')->getCollection();
$orderData=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
```

I want to combine them into single collection. Also where can I find payment method cause I don`t see it under orderData or transactionData collection.

Comment: What are you trying to find you get payment method details from order

Comment: Oh Okay I could`nt see in the collection when I was printing it but I fetched it by referring to the link below:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156933/get-payment-method-title-of-an-order
Now the question is how should I merge/join the collection?

Answer (score 0):

You can not merge two different collection in one

you can merge two same collection in one same as below example

```
$collection1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(148)->getProductCollection();
$collection2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(149)->getProductCollection();

$merged_ids = array_merge($collection1->getAllIds(), $collection2->getAllIds());
// can sometimes use "getLoadedIds()" as well

$merged_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $merged_ids))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

You can try one work around for your solution, you can create required field array from both collection and use it.

Comment: Oh Okay I`ll give a shot!

Answer (score 0):

***you can try below code to merge two collection in Magento Query***

---

```
$transactionData=Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment_transaction')->getCollection()->getSelect();
$orderData=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->getSelect();
$mergeCollection = $transactionData->union(array($orderData));
```

---

you can use ***unionall*** to prevent  duplicate records.

Comment: Your solution did`nt work for me!

Comment: is it showing any error ??
or you can not get result.

Comment: Nope it is not showing any error but I cannot see any output when I var_dump it!

Comment: try echo $mergeCollection->getSelect()

Comment: Still the same!